# Online - avatar Image with viewport

Tags: css, html, viewport

I am using viewport for this project in order to be responsive.

I want to have an avatar in the top right corner to show the user avatar and a green circle to show he is online.

Problem is I can't make the circle be responsive If I increase or decrease the size the circle will move. A couple of images:

**Big**

[image]

**Small**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<img class="img-header" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/129616/isolated/preview/fb517f8913bd99cd48ef00facb4a67c0-businessman-avatar-silhouette-by-vexels.png">

<p>Username</p>

<img class="online" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/e/E/F/G/p/g/alex-green-circle-md.png">
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.img-header {
position: relative;
margin-top: 0vw;
margin-right: 4vw;
float: right;
object-fit: cover;
border-radius:50%;
width: 7vw;
height: 7vw;
}

p{
float: right;
text-transform: bold;
margin-top: 1vw;
margin-right: 2vw;
display: inline;
font-size: 4vw;
}

.online {
width: 2vw;
position: absolute;
padding-left:92vw;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3e2e21z/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the image and the green icon image with a `div` then instead of `padding`, add `right` and `top` values for the green icon.

Now when it's big or small it will be at the same place, code below:

```css
.img-header {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0vw;
    margin-right: 4vw;
    float: right;
}
.img {
    width: 7vw;
    height: 7vw;
    border-radius: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
    vertical-align: super;
}
p {
    float: right;
    text-transform: bold;
    margin-top: 1vw;
    margin-right: 2vw;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 4vw;
}
.online {
    width: 2vw;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="img-header">
        <img class="img" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/129616/isolated/preview/fb517f8913bd99cd48ef00facb4a67c0-businessman-avatar-silhouette-by-vexels.png">
        <img class="online" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/e/E/F/G/p/g/alex-green-circle-md.png">
    </div>
    <p>Username</p>
</body>
```

And this is updated [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3e2e21z/1/).

Comment: That is just great, how did I forget that. Thank you.
One more thing the image seems to go down if you reduce the size of the display: https://ibb.co/j1COUb

Comment: You are most welcome :)  you could accept my answer as the correct one if this solved your issue.

Comment: Could you check my last comment before I accept the answer?

Comment: problem solved by adding `vertical-align: super;` to `.img`

Comment: That will do great. Thank you, I have accepted your answer.

Comment: you are welcome, but it seems that you didn't accept it or maybe something goes wrong.